# For the following VHDL Code

Tags: vhdl, computer-science

For the following VHDL code, assume that `D` changes to `'1'` at time 5 ns. Give the values of `A, B, C, D, E,` and `F` each time a change occurs. That is, give the values at time 5 ns, 5 + delta, 5 + 2(delta), etc. Carry this out until either 20 steps have occurred, until no further change occurs, or until a repetitive pattern emerges.

```
entity prob4 is

port (D: inout bit);

end prob4;

architecture q1 of prob4 is

signal A,B,C,E,F: bit;

begin

C <= A;

A <= (B and not E) or D;

P1: proecess (A)

begin

B <= A;

end prcoess P1;

P2: process

wait until A <= '1';

wait for 0 ns;

E <= B after 5 ns;

D < = '0';

F <= E;

end process P2;

end architecture q1;
```

Comment: please properly format your code, it'll go a long way with helping us help you.  Also, what's your question, what have you tried, where are you getting stuck.  As it stands right now it looks like you're wanting us to help you on homework, and that's not okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem as presented**

There are some obvious syntax errors:

```
entity prob4 is
    port (D: inout bit);   
end prob4;

architecture q1 of prob4 is
    signal A,B,C,E,F: bit;
begin

    C <= A;
    A <= (B and not E) or D;

P1: proecess (A)    -- misspelled process
    begin    
        B <= A;  
    end prcoess P1;  -- misspelled process

P2: process
    --  begin  -- missing begin

        wait until A <= '1';    
        wait for 0 ns;

        E <= B after 5 ns;  
        D < = '0';    -- should be "<=" (a single delimiter token signifying assignment)
        F <= E;
    end process P2;
end architecture q1;
```

Answering this problem appears to require you've paid attention to lectures, taken notes and/or done the required reading.

Note that there are two drivers one in process `P2` assigning `D`, the other the mode `inout` port `D`. There is no resolution for type BIT, implying some event not shown by the VHDL design specification is responsible for `D` to be assigned a value of `1` at 5 ns and that actual for port D isn't driven.  A resolution function can be associated with any subtype declaration (and a port declaration declares a subtype).

That isn't the case here:

```
entity tb_prob4 is
end entity;

architecture foo of tb_prob4 is
    signal D: bit;  
begin

DUT: 
    entity work.prob4 port map (D);  

STIMULUS:
    process
    begin
        D <= '1' after 5 ns;
    wait;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

> ghdl -a prob4 .vhdl
>   ghdl -e tb_prob4
>   ghdl -r tb_prob4
>   ./tb_prob4:error: several sources for unresolved signal
>   for signal: .tb_prob4(foo).ghdl: compilation error

You could theoretically answer the 'problem' supplied in your 'question' by stepping the simulation of an analyzed version of prob4 with the appropriate VHDL tool.  This would require forcing `D` to '1' at 5 ns and releasing it in the next delta cycle (after a step) in the device under test.  Otherwise it's a nonsense problem, the VHDL design specification is invalid (see above).  You could surmise the bit about "assume that D changes to '1'" was added to stave off questions about the validity.

**Solving the problem**

The problem can also also be done by hand (paper and pencil).

"... assume that D changes to '1' at time 5 ns" sounds like it implies a single event (no lasting force).

In VHDL an uninitialized signal will take the left most value, which for an enumerated value of type bit is '0' (See package std.standard). This tells you what everything is up to 5 ns.  (What's the initial value of A,B,C,D,E,F ?)

Delta cycles are inferred by assignment to the current simulation time. Simulation time advances when further signal assignments are scheduled for the current simulation time. Simulation time is then advanced to the next time a scheduled transaction is present in a projected output waveform for the modeled design hierarchy.

An `after` schedules a signal event in the projected output waveform for it's target.  In the example that would be the current value of `B` that is scheduled to be assigned to `D`.

Simulation time advances to the next time with an event (wait, after), `wait for 0 ns` refers to the current simulation time, will that cause a delta cycle?